# Вывести результат умножение на 5 с помощью цикл while

Tags: javascript, while

Написать код который выведет результат умножения чисел от 1 до 10 на 5.

Что я делаю не так?

```
var x = 5;
var y = 1;
var z = x * y;
while (z <= 50) {
    document.write(x + "x" + y + "=" + z + "<br>");
    y++;
}
```

Comment: Вычисление `z` переместите внутрь цикла.

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условие то так :)

```
var i =1; 
while (i<11){ 
   console.log(i*5); i++ 
}
```

Вывод будет в консоль браузера

Comment: _с помощью цикл while_

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 5,
    y = 1,
    z;
while (z < 50) {
  z = x * y;
  document.write(x + "x" + y + "=" + z + "<br>");
  y++;
}
```

Но, судя по заданию, результат умножения заранее неизвестен, потому правильнее проверку делать не по результату, а по значению переменной, которая будет умножаться:

```
var x = 5,
    y = 1;
while (y <= 10) {
  z = x * y;
  document.write(x + "x" + y + "=" + z + "<br>");
  y++;
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл `var z = "";`? почему вообще строка?

Comment: @Grundy сплоховал. исправил

Comment: не, оказывается присвоить значение перед проверкой все-таки надо, иначе цикл может даже не запуститься. Имеется ввиду цикл в котором проверяется `z`. При проверке `y` переменная `z` вообще не нужна

Comment: @lexxl отлично, теперь все работает, спасибо :)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, так понятнее)

Comment: @AnnaKukhareva если ответ вам подходит, можете принять его нажатием галочки слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

> Написать код который выведет результат умножения чисел от 1 до 10 на 5

По заданию понятно, что нужно вывести 1*5,2*5,3*5 ... 10*5.

```js
var i = 0;
while(i<10){
  i++;
  console.log(i*5);
}
```